# What Lego part(s) would hurt the most to step on?

Tags: plastics, piece-usage

We've all heard (and probably experienced) the long-running joke that stepping on a Lego is the absolute worst.

[People have determined](http://time.com/4246385/heres-why-it-hurts-so-much-to-step-on-a-lego/) this is due to the bricks' high compressive strength, small size, and sometimes sharp edges.

As far as edges are concerned, consider a standard 2x2 brick:
[image: Brick, Red, 2x2]
While the 6 faces are fairly harmless, if the brick were somehow angled such that a person put all their weight on an edge, or (god forbid) one of the 8 corners, it would really hurt.

So the question is: What Lego part, or assembly of Lego parts, would maximize both
 (a) small size, and
 (b) sharp edges/points pointed upwards when laying on the ground?

Comment: Old joke about D&D's infamous d4 die: Back when D&D first came out, it was highly controversial. For this reason, TSR included caltrops in game sets that you could throw down to slow persecutors down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this one would be in the top 5:

#### [Tile, Modified 2 x 2 with Pin (part 2460)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2460)

[image: Tile, Modified 2 x 2 with Pin 2460]

Comment: I was about to post this one as well. I can't think of any other single piece with such harmful potential.

Comment: The LEGO equivalent of a caltrop

Answer (score 9):

I nominate this little bugger:

[image: LEGO Pteranodon 30478]

Got it in a bulk lot, and oh boy is it painful to walk on. it rests flat on the ground thanks to the wings, and the crest is a nice touch for delicate underfoot.

Answer (score 7):

The 1x1 brick is both small enough to mean that you get edges no matter which way up it is, and has all the sharp edges and corners of the 2x2 brick, just packed into a smaller, more evil form.

That naturally leads to the headlight block, which has all the same features, but, if you are unfortunate, can also attack with the lip on the bottom.

[image: Evil brick]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

This assembly of pieces will not tickle, so let's dive in:

- First, the teeth are placed in reverse of each other so the foot and
  all that weight is forced to rock on the two little pointed tips.
- Second, the white circular base is wide enough to minimize rolling of
  the piece as experienced with a 2x2 brick, where the weight of a
  person would force the piece to roll instead of piercing foot
  flesh.  A wider surface area gives less relief of potential pain.
- Finally, a few 1x2 tile pieces to lock the teeth in place.  Without
  them the weight and force of a foot fall would dislodge the tooth from
  the base.

Chain a few of these together and Vwah-LAH!... I hereby dub thee the "Human Spike Strip". -Rin

Comment: If you covered a 32x32 base with those spikes, and stepped gently onto it, you'd get a proper bed of nails effect, looking like it would hurt a lot, but not actually being painful

Answer (score 3):

Several roof tiles and similar triangular parts must be strong contenders.  Here's a selection I could quickly lay my hands on:[image: painful Lego, in blue]

The one on the right ([13548 "Wedge 2 x 2 (Slope 45 Corner)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13548)) wouldn't be so bad as the other 3 pictured, or the classic 2x2 roof tile.  The front one ([3049c "Blue Slope 45 2 x 1 Double / Inverted"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3049c)) would be particularly evil, except it's very slightly rounded on the tip.

Answer (score 1):

> We've all heard (and probably experienced) the long-running joke that stepping on a Lego is the absolute worst.

Those people have clearly never stepped barefoot on a [UK 13A plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets:_British_and_related_types#BS_1363-1_Rewirable_and_non-rewirable_13_A_fused_plugs) sitting on the floor with it's pins facing upwards.

Lego have sold a number of power bricks over the years the older ones tend to be the best for sitting stably in a pin-up position though, something like [part 70928b "Electric, Train Speed Regulator 9V Power Adapter 240V (UK)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=70928b):

[image: part 70928b]

Answer (score 0):

I think the most painful Lego honestly has to go to the Lego Crystal; just try it on a base plate.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think this single bevel gear would probably hurt a lot:

[image: Id 3650: LEGO Technic Gear 24 tooth crown with reinforcements]

Comment: While that looks super spiky there are enough points that it can spread the load

Comment: As I remember it, there are not many sharp edges on those.

Answer (score -5):

no the lego ax and the lego spear from the medieval sets, clipped onto the side holster of the saddle on the lego horse.  Oh, and the lego horse's head is pointed up and its mouth is open and it's bitting...yeah just bitting at the air above its head at random intervals with a taste for human flesh of the barefoot variety.

PS. Megablox are sharper

Answer (score -6):

The little swords from the medieval-themed sets such as this one:

[image: a minifig sword]

Comment: Only harmful if somehow pointing straight up; unlikely unless stuck in a crevice in the flooring which is even more unlikely!